# Better way to insert data in table from other table with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have two tables:

Table1 - MainTable

```
---------------------------------------
| MainTableID | CustomerName | BookID |
---------------------------------------
```

Table2 - BookTable

```
----------------------
| BookID | BookName  |
----------------------
|   1    |  physics  |
----------------------
|   2    |   Math    |
----------------------
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
---------------------------------------
| MainTableID | CustomerName | BookID |
---------------------------------------
|      1      |     Alex     |  Math  |
---------------------------------------
```

I have list of BookNames in BookTable and I want to insert Data in MainTable. I am using ADO.NET entity data model in visual studio and I am doing this so:

```
BookTable correspondingBook=(from row in entities.BookTable
                             where rows.BookName == "Math"
                             select rows).First();

MainTable itemToAdd = new MainTable();

itemToAdd.CustomerName = "Alex";
itemToAdd.BookID = correspondingBook.BookID;

entities.MainTable.Add(itemToAdd);

entities.SaveChanges();
```

Is it good solution for this problem? if no, Which will be better?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using ADO.NET?? Because from your  code i see only EF method. So, try to read that constants (like: Math,Alex) from configurable file

Comment: I add my project ADO.NET entity data model, which created ([DataBaseName]entities class) and entities in my code is it's object...